# How do i find the duration between two timings for multiple events?

Tags: python, datetime, duration

My task is to find out how long the bus is charged for, and when charging type = 1, it means that the charger is plugged in. How do i find the duration from this? Also i need to find out the charging frequency, is there a way i can do that too?

Here is the code currently:

```
#Duration loop
foundEnd = False

for i in range(len(dfDur01Mar22)):
    #only display bus 'SG3079S'
    if dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,1] == 'SG3079S':
        #print 'end' when first '0' appears
        if not foundEnd and dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,2] == 0:
            print('end')
            foundEnd = True
        #if charging type is 1
        elif dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,2] == 1:
            print(dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,0],dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,1],dfDur01Mar22.iloc[i,2])
            foundEnd = False
```

and here is the output from it :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkv6H.png)

Comment: Can you comment where you want the timing to start and where you want it to end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the datetime module to figure out the amount of time between 2 events:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now()
#Func here
end = datetime.now()

total = end - start

seconds_elapsed = total.total_seconds()

print (seconds_elapsed)
```